# Which irrigation valve should I use?

Tags: solenoid-valve

I am looking for an element that permits me to irrigate automatically. I have seen that it exists something called solenoid valve. However, this valves require a continuous electrical consumption and in my case it cannot be allowed. They exist latching solenoid valves, that maintain a permanent magnetic field saving a lot of energy. Unfortunately, I have some problems with them:

- I have been unable to find any datasheet.
- They seem to be unable to permit high flows (I would need up to 10 liters/second).
- They are said to be insecure.

So, the question is: Should I use a latching solenoid valve (and in that case, where could I find one?) or does there exist a preferred system such as, for example, an electric water tap?

Comment: google water valve electrically operated latching

Comment: You could also look for motor operated valves.